# Retrieve lost data from my jawbone up3

Tags: jawbone

I accidentally deleted my Jawbone UP app, I had 2, one being old from my Up24 and I recently realized it was only taking up space as an unused app but I accidentally deleted the new app I currently use for my up3.

Only different when it shows app icons for deleting is color.
 I obviously now regret not making sure of the color to my new UP app. But too late for hindsight to help.

When I re-downloaded it, all my  data from the past year is gone. It oddly kept the past 8 days which maybe is a default for all I know to only save the current week?  Otherwise this makes no sense.I have tried everything in my phone and SD card. Nothing has an available cache from why I can see.

Then I went on jawbone.com to look up my data as I was told they backed it up there...
 I did not know this before. But I went on and shows me the list, I forget what it's called but it has all year blank but has the last 8 days filled like it's all the data ever saved. I didn't delete anything from actual jawbone, only the stupid app and quickly reinstalled it. Only to find out all my 11 months of data, experience, goals, progress etc all gone. And now the UP app is treating me like a new "UPster" and I'm not. It doesn't seem to even know anything from smart coaches previous tasks and helpful suggestions based on me. Now it's all gone. I didn't write this down because I thought that's why may this app was for.

In the age of everything cloud storage it's appalling to see this has no such thing or backup that I see at all. Likely I lost all but hoping theirs a trick or a website or something I'm not aware of and could help. I also know some information in a phone even if deleted isn't actually deleted and I have been able to retrieve others deleted like they had a background copy of the data. This however does not seem to be the same. No matter what I do or where I go it seems that I have lost all data history.

I now have no desire or need for this useless bracelet if it won't even do the one thing I need it to, collect data and build progress with smart coach getting to know me. If the data is gone the point to all I was using the tracker for is now also gone. How is it not online where it says it should be? I'm assuming my app deletion also deleted any backups I may have had. And that's where I'm lost isn't that what backups like that are for?  It now only shows me a week behind. The rest is gone. I don't know but I would imagine I could retrieve data lost. Otherwise why collect data. I was looking in my cloud drives but nothing is there. I just want what I lost, back.

Does it delete all cached items?
And why?

I should have my own account and I should be able to access it and look at and or retrieve my past information. Anyway I can I just need to know if possible and if so how do I get the data back? Or even manually input it because I have all my old weekly reviews on my Google account but they don't seem to be anything other than an email I can only look at. It won't sync or share info and without it being on the up app it does no good because I have no smart coach, nothing to relate new days to old ones with. Nothing. It doesn't even work with smart coach and that seems quite odd.

I had an account since day 1 and it is the same account I tried taking data files out of. I messaged Jawbone but it says 3 days before I get a reply. I'm feeling like Ill just need to give up but I've been sick for several years and this had literally been a lifeline to better health, motivation I've lost and need, support since I have no trainer to keep me focused or mindset...I got this to help while I have been Ill.  This just posses me off real bad.  not having all my old data. This seems ridiculous.

Comment: Looking at this paragraph discourage me from reading.

Comment: Improved title + formatted big post...

Comment: You should contact Jawbone customer support for this kind of issue: https://help.jawbone.com/contact

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry you're having these issues. In general, Jawbone does not delete any historical data unless you specifically [request data/account deletion](https://jawbone.com/user/settings#!accounts). Deleting the app from your phone should not remove data from the Jawbone servers unless that data had never been synced, which seems unlikely since you have the 8 most recent days.

One thing you should double-check is to make sure you're logging in with exactly the same email address that you had been using.

All this being said, contacting Jawbone customer support is the best way to solve your problem. If you haven't already, please reach out via the contact form:
https://help.jawbone.com/contact

The Jawbone tag on Stack Overflow is for programming questions related to the Jawbone UP API.